# styling text vs styling an button

Tags: html, css

If i style `input` then the height affects a text input different then a button.
Why is this? And what can be done about it?
(and as a extra, why don't they align?)

[image]

```
<input type="text" value="foobar"/>
<input type="button" value="foobar"/>
```

css:

```
body {
    background: red;
}

input {
    border: 0;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/sxbzav34/

Comment: Look at the solution by "Alex Char" below. You can see others answers for the "why" which is because browsers apply their own styles to the different element types.  CSS allows you to override them, and where no style override is explicitly specified, the browser default takes place or it is inherited from the parent containers if the parent has a style that can propegate. An example, would be the "line-height" style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of html elements such as input of type button has predefined styles in browsers. Among others, this results into input of type button to have `box-sizing: border-box`. Enforce this to be `box-sizing: content-box`, so your css will look like:

```
body {
    background: red;
}

input {
    border: 0;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: I have chosen this as the accepted answer but I recommend to read the answer of Alex Char as well.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to set `line-height` instead of height:

```css
body {
    background: red;
}
input {
    border: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="foobar"/>
<input type="button" value="foobar"/>
```

Fix: After testing on other browsers discover an issue. You have to use specific `padding` e.g. `padding: 0 10px;`(top and bottom have to be 0)

Comment: odd, when i was trying that in the sandbox, it didn't work XD

Comment: Thanks for one more time for downvote without comment.

Comment: I up-voted this, for the record.  I think yours provides the best solution here.  If you leave the values blank, they do show mis-aligned.  This is definitely a very odd issue :)

Comment: Isn't setting the `box-sizing` explicitly better than doing so for `line-height`? After investigating the default style applied in Chrome it seems like `box-sizing` is the one causing this issue, while setting `line-height` is more of a workaround maybe?

Comment: I wonder the same about `box-sizing: content-box;`. But before i choose a definite answer i would love to hear some opinions about this.

Comment: @clankill3r then in chrome right click the input of type button, choose "investigate" and investigate the default css style applied to it in Chrome. You should see `box-sizing: border-box;`, while I failed to find similar override of `line-height`.

Comment: @Alex Char setting the padding is just yet another way to work around `box-sizing: border-box` as opposed to behaviour with `content-box` which is default.

Comment: @AlexChar how did you create the "run code snippet" thing?

Answer (score 1):

The size differs because the vertical padding is not added to the size of the button, but it is added to the size of the textbox. You can use `height` and `line-height` to set the height and vertical position of the text.

The alignment is off because they have different vertical alignment by default. If you specify a vertical alignment they will align themselves equally.

```
input {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border: 0;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/kx7wzufr/

Answer (score 0):

Because of default styling of browsers. Give them different classes and style them.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign two different classes to your text input field and the input button and then style them accordingly, please check this: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sxbzav34/3/).

HTML:

```
<input class="text" type="text" value="foobar" />
<input class="button" type="button" value="foobar" />
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: red;
}
.text {
    border: 0;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.button {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 12px 12px 13px 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each browser gives inputs special styling. If you take a look at Chrome developer tools and scroll down a little bit you'll see something along the lines of below. You have to overwrite those styles by adding a class or using input[type="button"]:

```
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"], input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button, button {
align-items: flex-start;
text-align: center;
cursor: default;
color: buttontext;
padding: 2px 6px 3px;
border: 2px outset buttonface;
border-image-source: initial;
border-image-slice: initial;
border-image-width: initial;
border-image-outset: initial;
border-image-repeat: initial;
background-color: buttonface;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```